# Decrypt SSL traffic with the openssl command line tool 7

Tags: encryption, ssl, tls, public-key, rsa

Generating the master secret/key I followed the steps outlined in my shell script. I validated that I am passing data correctly to it by manually entering these steps several times (entering $key manually) and ultimately I arrive at the same outcome/data
in this case

key = decrypted pre master key from previous step

```
03033ab0d673caefc4a9f6d35cf51d349815d67a09ac454f11dfb9741c96001a
66a3e82f688b82138403018384cf35f2
```

mseed.key = "master secret" + client.random + server.random
The file is a binary file when I use that the hexdump xxd -p mseed.key so you can see the data:

```
6d617374657220736563726574 5b689404b500456eef2f1a79ec782eb3ee
aac3a8d7c02ae03c8426f363b18a33 5b6894043bb1289e158b0278ef66dc
53c9fa71e75e900739af2657cd4476ec1e

Note: the spaces are not in the data I added those manually to make it clear
```

client.random 
xxd -p crnd.bin

```
5b689404b500456eef2f1a79ec782eb3eeaac3a8d7c02ae03c8426f363b1
8a33
```

server.random
xxd - srnd.bin

```
5b6894043bb1289e158b0278ef66dc53c9fa71e75e900739af2657cd4476
ec1e
```

just so I am clear those randoms also include the unix time prefixed (correct?)

```
key=${1} #passed to shell script 
openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key <mseed.key -binary >a1
openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key <a1 -binary >a2
openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key <a2 -binary >a3
openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key <a3 -binary >a4
```

The next step is:

```
cat a1 mseed.key | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key -binary >k1
cat a2 mseed.key | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key -binary >k2
cat a3 mseed.key | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key -binary >k3   
cat a4 mseed.key | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$key -binary >k4
```

Follwed by extracting the master secret

```
cat k1 k2 | head -c48 | xxd -p -c48 > master_secret.hex
truncate -s-1 master_secret.hex
```

master_secret at this point

```
$cat master_secret.hex
ee45b637f95ddf3b3bf51661cdf4e07bdd63a67f2d2df776322992b3fd871fe4ba38debcd7179bf4
ef8b8bb814fe4544d
```

From my wireshark log I extracted the client random during the conversation and saved it as the binary file crnd.bin

```
Random: 5b689404b500456eef2f1a79ec782eb3eeaac3a8d7c02ae0...
    GMT Unix Time: Aug  6, 2018 14:31:32.000000000 Eastern Daylight Time
    Random Bytes: b500456eef2f1a79ec782eb3eeaac3a8d7c02ae03c8426f3...
```

Subsequently I capture the server time and random bytes and save it as srnd.bin

```
Random: 5b6894043bb1289e158b0278ef66dc53c9fa71e75e900739...
    GMT Unix Time: Aug  6, 2018 14:31:32.000000000 Eastern Daylight Time
    Random Bytes: 3bb1289e158b0278ef66dc53c9fa71e75e900739af2657cd...
```

Dave, At this point I am stumped what I could be missing. I don't think I am missing something like a null in a variable or anything I've meticulously gone over the data and steps and don't see what I could be missing. Do you spot anything with these steps?
Thanks

Comment: Your `cat master_secret.hex` _shows_ a stray character `d` on the end; that makes it 97 hexits (48 and a half bytes), and the correct-length value I compute ends after `4544`. But the commands you show shouldn't have caused this; I would wonder if this is actually an artifact of displaying a file with no newline in your environment (shell? terminal?). BTW if you're going to _use_ this value with shell command substitution `$(cat master)` (or the older equivalent with backticks) you don't need to remove the newline yourself; that _automatically_ removes trailing newlines.

Comment: Shoot master_secret.hex does not have that d sorry about that. ee45b637f95ddf3b3bf51661cdf4e07bdd63a67f2d2df776322992b3fd871fe4ba38debcd7179bf4
ef8b8bb814fe4544d
I accidently cut to much the "d" is actually part of my prompt

Comment: Given that the "d" problem you noted is not actually in my data I posted the last of my steps and the subsequent data I am using [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1347869/decrypt-ssl-traffic-with-the-openssl-command-line-tool-8) (I'm still waiting on my system admin to help set up the connection using openssl and the logs)